# Djcelery obsolete, but how allow user to add periodic tasks without it?

Tags: celery, djcelery

Djcelery is now to be regarded as obsolete, but using just plane celery and django I don't see a way to allow an app admin user to schedule a periodic task. I can hardcode one into the django settings file using CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE, but that is it?

It seems I'd have to use the database backend, then make my own PeriodicTask model, essentially repeating what djcelery already does?